# Не работает бот для дискорда

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

```js
const Discord=require('discord.js');
const robot= new Discord.Client();
robot.login("мой токен");

robot.on('message',(message)=>{
 if(message.content =="лох"){
  message.reply("сам лох");
 }
});
```

```
C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\бот для дискорда>node bot.js
(node:3620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
(node:3620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Запускаю через консоль cmd выдаёт такую ошибку папка node-modules присутствует

Comment: `Incorrect login details were provided.` Все же написано.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй строку `robot.login("мой токен")` написать последней, а вместо `message.reply` напиши `message.channel.send`. Должно помочь